# How do I solve an ambiguous operator overload issue?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class `Fraction` defined as:

```
class Fraction
{
  int d_numerator;
  int d_denominator;

  Fraction(numerator, denominator)
    :
  d_numerator(numerator), d_denominator(denominator)
  {}

  Fraction(double number)
    :
  d_numerator(static_cast<int>(number * 100000)), d_denominator(100000)
  {}
};
```

I need to overload `operator+` to allow me to add 2 `Fraction` objects:

```
Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction& other)
{
  Fraction result = Add(other); //Add() implementation omitted for brevity
  return result;
}
```

I have an overloaded `operator(double)`function that allows me to cast `Fraction` objects to type `double` e.g `double b = (double)a;` where `a` is of type `Fraction`.

```
Fraction::operator(double){//omitted for brevity}
```

I want to be able to add a `double` to a `Fraction` like this: `Fraction c = a + 2.6;`

The issue is this will not compile since there are several ways of interpreting the conversion of the statement `Fraction c = a + 2.6;`

I get the following compiler error:

error C2666: 'Fraction::operator +': 3 overloads have similar conversions
could be

1. 'Fraction Fraction::operator +(const Fraction &)
2. or built-in C++ operator+(double, double)
3. or built-in C++ operator+(float, double)

I think the essence of this is, should the compiler:

1. convert the `Fraction a` to a double using the `operator(double)` overload and add the two doubles
2. or, convert the double 2.6 to a `Fraction` using the constructor that allows for this and add the two `Fractions`?

Is there a way to force the compiler to use one route of the other, or to just let it pick either. I don't mind as long as the result is as expected.

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest making the constructor that takes a `double`, an `explicit` constructor. This is probably a good idea anyway.

Comment: `const` is missing, olso defining `operator+` as member function has impact on overload resolution.

Comment: Could you share a complete example? `Fraction::operator(double)` looks rather odd, and I don't know what that means.

Comment: Implicit conversions very often turn out to not be such a good idea as they seemed at first. (Case in point: C++.)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to be able to add a double to a Fraction like this: `Fraction c = a + 2.6;`
>
> The issue is this will not compile since there are several ways of interpreting the conversion of the statement `Fraction c = a + 2.6`;

You have an implicit conversion operator (from `Fraction` to `double`) and also an implicit conversion constructor (from `double` to `Fraction`) and both result in valid matches for `operator+` and the compiler refuses to continue with that ambiguity.

Making the conversions `explicit` is what's recommended but if you *really* want `Fraction c = a + 2.6` to work, you could settle for making the conversion *to* `double` explicit. That means that you'll have to `static_cast<double>(a)` if you want to convert `a` to a `double`.

I've made a working example for adding two `Fraction`s with comments in the code. Extending it with the other operators is left as an exercise.

```
#include <iostream>

class Fraction {
public:
    Fraction(int numerator, int denominator) :
        d_numerator(numerator), d_denominator(denominator) 
    {}

    // a converting constructor for double
    Fraction(double number) :
        d_numerator(static_cast<int>(number * 1000000)), d_denominator(1000000)
    {}

    // add a Fraction to *this
    Fraction& operator+=(const Fraction& o) {
        d_numerator = d_numerator * o.d_denominator + o.d_numerator * d_denominator;
        d_denominator *= o.d_denominator;
        return *this;
    }

    // explicit conversion to double
    explicit operator double() const {
        return static_cast<double>(d_numerator) / d_denominator;
    }

private:
    int d_numerator;
    int d_denominator;
};

// A free function to add two Fractions - take the left hand side by value
// and you can return the same object (after having added the right hand side to it).
Fraction operator+(Fraction a, const Fraction& b) {
    // use the member operator+=
    return a += b;
}
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/AdNpFj)

In the demo I've made use of the C++17 function [`std::gcd`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/gcd) because it's nice to have the numbers as small as possible when working with fractions and it has streaming to support printing.

Comment: @MooingDuck There... I think I got all non-essential stuff removed and put it in a demo instead.